# WCF serialization - double nested

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I am trying to create a service that returns a List as one data member along with other string data members.

The service is working but returns a structure with the list that is nested too deep.  Like this:

```
a:Name> </a:Name>
<a:Phone> </a:Phone>
<a:Offices> 
<a:Offices> 
<a: Office Name>  </a:Office Name>
<a: Office Address>  </a:Office Address>
<a: Office eMail>  </a:Office eMail>
</a:Offices> 
<a:Offices> 
<a: Office Name>  </a:Office Name>
<a: Office Address>  </a:Office Address>
<a: Office eMail>  </a:Office eMail>
</a:Offices> 
</a:Offices>
```

What I need it to return is a structure like this:

```
<a:Name> </a:Name>
<a:Phone> </a:Phone>
<a:Offices> 
<a: Office Name>  </a:Office Name>
<a: Office Address>  </a:Office Address>
<a: Office eMail>  </a:Office eMail>
</a:Offices> 
<a:Offices> 
<a: Office Name>  </a:Office Name>
<a: Office Address>  </a:Office Address>
<a: Office eMail>  </a:Office eMail>
</a:Offices>
```

My data contract is structured like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{

[DataMember(Name = "Name", Order = 1)]
public string Name{ get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Phone", Order = 2)]
public string Phone{ get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Offices", Order = 3)]
public List<Offices> offices{ get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Offices
{
[DataMember(Name = "Office Name", Order = 1)]
public string OfficeName{ get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Office Address", Order = 2)]
public string OfficeAddress{ get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Office eMail", Order = 3)]
public string OfficeeMail{ get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need the structure of your object to look like this.  Note, I have not tested this.

```
   [DataContract]
   public class Person
   {

        [DataMember(Name = "Name", Order = 1)]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Phone", Order = 2)]
        public string Phone{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "List Item 1", Order = 3)]
        public List<string> ListItem1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "List Item 2", Order = 4)]
        public List<string> ListItem2 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "List Item 3", Order = 5)]
        public List<string> ListItem3 { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  The list was intended to be a set of attributes for office locations.  Where List Item 1 = Office Name, List Item 2= Office Address, List Item 3= Office eMail.   I revised the original question to reflect this.  Should I still try to break out the Lists in the way you suggested?